# border radius and border width in Opera

Tags: html, border, opera, css

I have such code:

HTML:

```
<div class="round">some text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.round {
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-right-width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

The problem occures in only the opera browser on the right side of div, which has truncated corner in the border.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HddwE/1/

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Opera 17.0

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the o-border-radius setting? maybe you are working with an old opera version?

Comment: it seems that in opera the border-with can only be as high as the border-radius. looks like s strange substraction miscalculation. I did some little trick to get it working. check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ks2QG/